# Calendar-like apps that allow more flexible timing of events & notifications?

Tags: calendar, notification, timer, alarm-clock

I'm looking for an app (best for Win11, but Android is ok) that is almost identical to, say, Google calendar, but it must have 2 more features:

- It allows creating events in the past. For example, today is 4Dec, but if I want to create an event on 28Nov now, it's still ok.
- It allows creating notifications after the event. All alarms in gg cal are "backward in time", which means x hours or y days or z weeks before the event. I want forward-in-time ones, like a month after. So in our example, it will ring the bells on 28Dec.

In case there's no such app, is it hard for someone to code it on existing ones? Thanks.